# Unexpected error reading GML graph

Tags: python-3.4, networkx, archlinux

I have downloaded the gml file which contains the [dolphins social network](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/netdata/dolphins.zip).

Some time ago I did some analysis on that network running python 3.4 and **networkx 1.9** on a a Windows7 machine, but now I am running on a Arch linux machine (with the same version of python but **with networkx 1.10**) and found an issue when tried to read the file.

This is the code used to read the file:

```
import networkx as nx
nx.read_gml("dolphins.gml")
```

And this is the stack trace of the error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 2, in read_gml
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.py",line 220, in _open_file
result = func(*new_args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gml.py", line 210, in read_gml
G = parse_gml_lines(filter_lines(path), label, destringizer)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gml.py", line 383, in parse_gml_lines
graph = parse_graph()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gml.py", line 372, in parse_graph
curr_token, dct = parse_kv(next(tokens))
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gml.py", line 323, in tokenize
(line[pos:], lineno + 1, pos + 1))
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: cannot tokenize 'graph' at (1, 1)
```

Are you able to read the file? Someone has experienced a simmilar issue? or knows what is generating the error?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Strange - it worked for me (yes, I have also used the dolphins network).  I'm running networkx 2.0.dev_20151001131915 in python 2.7.

Comment: You might be running into the same thing as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31946029/networkx-read-gml-error-networkx-exception-networkxerror-cannot-tokenize-ugra But no-one has given an answer there.

Comment: Here is the source code for `read_gml` http://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/networkx/readwrite/gml.html It looks like the error message is coming from not finding a match in some regex.

Comment: Hi Joel, mine also is 2.2.1... I also looked the source code but didn't understand why that regex can be failing, it is possible that the problem can be due to the file  enconding or something like that?

Comment: I generated a graph using the erdos-renyi model and wrote it into a gml file and was able to read it. Additionally, I load that gml file using gephi and exported as gexf, then read the gexf using networkx without problems but when I tried to exported to gml appeared a new error: raise NetworkXError('%r is not a valid key' % (key,))
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: 'edge_default' is not a valid key

Comment: I tried copy and paste in a new file but didn't work. I will let you know if I find a solution, thank you Joel for your time!

Comment: @Joel I changed the version to 1.9.1 and it worked, How can I install the version you have to try if it works with the version 2?

Comment: I'm actually not sure where I downloaded the version I have (it's a development version)...  I assume I got it off of github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked by downgrading the networkx version from 1.10 to 1.9.1.

Hope this answer can help someone else.

Comment: Looks like the gml readers/writers in 1.9.1 were very "flexible" (not many checks performed on node and edge attributes - just tried to read them in as best as possible and interpret attributes as GML-appropriate types - lists, dicts, or strings)

Later versions (1.10, 1.11) seem to have implemented a number of checks that make reading/writing older files a bit tough. For example, in 1.11, you can't assign node or edge attribute keys with underscores!  Bit of an annoyance. See here: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/readwrite/gml.html

Answer (score 5):

In the newer versions of networkx, the gml file should follow a more specific format. The problem with the dolphins.gml is that there should not be any carriage return before the open square brackets. For example:

Wrong format:

```
graph 
[
  directed 0
  node 
  [
    id 0
    label "Beak"
  ]
  .
  .
  .
```

Correct format:

```
graph [
  directed 0
  node [
    id 0
    label "Beak"
  ]
  .
  .
  .
```

It does not care about how many spaces there are before the square bracket as long as there is more than one and there is no carriage return.

What I ended up doing was using regular expression to get rid of the white spaces before the opening square brackets. The following regex worked for me:

```
\s+\[
```

and just replace it with " [". There has to be at least one space before the bracket.

Also keep in mind that every node has to have a unique label.

Hope it helped.

Comment: In the case someone searches for a sed command: `sed -i 'N;s/\s\+\[/ \[/g;P;D' dolphins.gml`

Comment: According to the GML specs, newlines before `[` are fine. If a software does not accept GML files like this, it's a bug in that software.